# Separating values based on comma using list

Tags: php, list, explode

I am trying to separate a string based on the comma.

I have the following text -

```
Hello world 1
Hello world 2
[18657,18669]
Hello world 3
[12321]
Hello world 4
[45342,23421]
```

The code -

```
$separator = "\r\n";
$line = strtok($article_content, $separator);
$id = array();
while ($line !== false) {
    # do something with $line
    $line = strtok( $separator );
    echo $line;
    preg_match('#\[(.*?)\]#', $line, $match);
    if(isset($match[1])){
        echo "found--".$match[1];
        list($id) = explode(",", $match[1]);
        var_dump($id);
    }
}
```

The list function is taking the first value for eg
`[18657,18669]` -> list is getting 18657 only.

How can I get separated values for eg

```
18657
18669
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `list($id)` is just getting the first item, change this to just `$id` and see what happens.

Comment: @RiggsFolly   Can't use list($id1,$id2)  because the numbers can be [1,2,3,4]

Comment: @NigelRen that's the trick...thank you..All good